# I get prisma client deprecated on running prisma studio

Tags: prisma

Any time I run the `npx prisma studio` command I get this output:

```
Environment variables loaded from .env
Prisma schema loaded from prisma\schema.prisma
Prisma Studio is up on http://localhost:5555
imports from "@prisma/client/runtime" are deprecated.
Use "@prisma/client/runtime/library",  "@prisma/client/runtime/data-proxy" or  "@prisma/client/runtime/binary"
```

And I've not found anything on their documentation that says how to fix it. Also this happened after I deleted my yarn.lock file and did the yarn command to install dependencies in my package.json.

I tried restarting the server, even restarting my system

Comment: What prisma version are you using?

Answer (score 1):

If you were using prisma 4.9.x and then upgraded to 4.10.1 try to invoke again `npx prisma generate`, the error will likely be resolved after this

If it doesn't help try to start prisma studio using this command

```
dotenv -e .envrc -- prisma studio --browser=none
```